# Convert a scala Set of Strings to a Set of Long

Tags: scala

how can I convert a Scala set of strings

```
val s = Set("1","2","3")
```

to a set of long?

```
Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val s = Set("1","2","3")
val longs = s.map(_.toLong)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `long` value check:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val s = Set("1", "2", "3", "x")

s.map( x => Try(x.toLong) match {
  case Success(e) => e
  case Failure(_) => -999L
} )
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Long] = Set(1, 2, 3, -999)
```